# Hiding Toolbar and navigation in SSRS report inside an IFrame

Tags: php, iframe, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have deployed an SSRS report on my local server and now am planning to render this report on a web page using IFrame.Its a PHP application

IFrame displays the report but also displays the tool bar and navigation links on the top of the report.

Could some help me hide the tool bar and the navigation links on the top of the report.

Used `&rc:Toolbar=false` as suggested in the [this_link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx) but there was no change.

Link am using to navigate to the report

```
http://<computername>/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fReport+Project1%2fReport1&rc:Toolbar=false
```

Any other better alternatives to render the SSRS report apart from using IFrame in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You obviously didn't bother to read the page you linked to before posting this question. Your URL looks nothing like the examples.

You should be pointing to a /reportserver style URL, not /Reports.

Comment: I am new to SSRS and wanted to know the exact URL transformation that's described in the link.I went through the link.