# Hide parameters from SSRS Report when it Renders inside an iframe

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have go through this question about the same topic in stack overflow but i did not get any accurate answers from the same that is why i have ask the question again

[Hiding Toolbar and navigation in SSRS report inside an IFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727903/hiding-toolbar-and-navigation-in-ssrs-report-inside-an-iframe)

I havce created a ssrs report and i have render it in an iframe using it's url

then problem is i need to hide the parameter details because it contains some sensitive infromations

i had tried something like below

```
$('#ifrme_reportView').attr('src',http://localhost/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2MyReport%2fViewReport&rs:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=false&PID="+PID+"&ID="+ID+"")
```

but it still shows the parameters

but when i paste this url directly in browser then the parameter part is hidden

why it happneds like this ??
is there any way to hide the parameters from ssrs reports when it render it in an iframe ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `rc:Paramaters=False` in your URL string twice. In my experience, having `rc:Toolbar=False` in a URL twice causes the Toolbar to show regardless, so I suspect you're hitting the same problem.

Try:

```
$('#ifrme_reportView').attr('src',http://localhost/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2MyReport%2fViewReport&rs:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=false&PID="+PID+"&ID="+ID+"")
```

Dan

Comment: sorry it was a typing mistake . that is not the real problem

Comment: Ah. Then, I am afraid I am not sure. I have successfully gotten a report to run in an iframe without the parameters showing using this URL, maybe you can spot something different between our attempts: `<iframe src="https://reporting.progresso.net/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fUsers+Folders%2fUser%2fMy+Reports%2fSATS+CATS+Set+lists+by+teacher&rs:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=false&KS3AP=AP3&Y10AP=AP3&Y11AP=AP5&KS5AP=AP5&StaffList=58060" height="400" width="1800" />`